# Android MVVM databinding brakes build

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I have tested this a few times. After adding the following code my project fails to build. The immediate error is "Symbol 'R' failed to load."

**app Gradle:**

```
dataBinding{
    enabled = true
}
```

**Layout File:**

```
<data>
    <variable android:name="games" android:type="com.mydomain.mypackage.GameListViewModel"/>
</data>
```

**Activity File:**

```
ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_game_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "android:" in the name and type of the variable. 
The error you're getting happens usually when you have an error in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

modify layout file:

```
   <data>
    <variable
        name="games"
        type="com.mydomain.mypackage.GameListViewModel" />
</data>
```